# Line integral formula

Tags: integration, line-integrals

I am studying line integrals and I came across this formula:

$$ \operatorname{Area}(\Sigma) = h\,l(C) = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \left\| \gamma'(t) \right\| dt = \int_\gamma f. $$

It's clear that the area is $height \cdot base$, but isn't it all included in $\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))$, since the integral gives the area under a specific function?

Comment: I think that what is missing here is that the area found is the one extended from the curve all the way to the function over it, just like extending a screen from the curve to the function. Is that screen's area that you're evaluating here.